# Charging system on 12 volt battery

Tags: diodes

Which post does a 12 volt battery charge from, positive or negative? I've been told it charges from negative.

Comment: Both terminals are used for charging. Current goes into the positive and comes out of the negative,

Comment: Welcome! Please look up Kirchhoff’s current law. Current only flows in loops.

Comment: in any given schematic you have seen, it might appear that one post is connected to something boring like ground, and the other to interesting things like transistors and so on, and you might be tempted to think that the latter is the 'active' terminal. Both terminals are used to pass current all the time, whether charging or discharging. If you trace the circuit, you will find that current always enters one and leaves the other in exactly equal amounts, whether through the ground lead or the more interesting looking one. Break the ground connection, the battery stops working with the circuit

Answer (score 4):

The question about "which post" is meaningless. Both posts are used all the time. It is like asking whether riding a bike uses the top or the bottom of the chain.

The battery naturally wants to push current out of the positive post and into the negative post. If we let it do that, it discharges. To recharge the battery, the charger must overpower the battery wanting to discharge, and force the current to go in the other direction, into the positive post and out of the negative post.